# AsyncTask loop doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm creating an application which communicates with a web service.

I have a method heartBeat I would like to call asynchronous every 5secs or so. My problem is not how to do this asynchronous. But how I keep the job done. I use a inner class which inherit from AsyncTask. My question is how can I start this thread every 5sec?

I have tried something like from doInBackground()

```
while (true) {
  ...
  Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

but I also need the return statement, to tell the UI thread whatever the web service is available or not.

Comment: check the link for timing http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/scheduling-a-timer-task-to-run-repeatedly/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `publishProgress()` from within `doInBackgroound()` and then do UI stuff in `onProgressUpdate()`